# Azure VM with multiple nics

Tags: networking, server, azure

I'm trying to build an Ubuntu Server 20.04 server with two nics as per this documentation - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/multiple-nics.

The VM is deployed with one nic in the frontend subnet and one in the backend and I have the following netplan config and routes:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 100
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                driver: hv_netvsc
                macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:00
            set-name: eth0
        eth1:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 200
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                driver: hv_netvsc
                macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:00
            set-name: eth1
            routes:
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 172.22.40.65

    version: 2

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.22.40.65    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         172.22.40.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   172.22.40.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 172.22.40.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.22.40.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
172.22.40.64    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1
```

172.22.40.65 is the gateway address for the backend subnet, I've anonymised the mac addresses.

From eth0 I can get out to the internet and ping my firewall in a peered vnet, however from eth1 I can do neither. Is there something obvious I'm missing to get this to work?

Any advice is most appreciated

Comment: @muru - Apologies, fixed.